# fadeIn function on Scilab

Tags: fadein, scilab

I'm currently working on a function supposed to create a fade in on a charged song... 
It's barely working. The problem is that it's not respecting the duration of the fadeIn that we ask.
For example, if I mention a duration of 20sec and the other 50sec, it's doing the exact same fadeIn (which is lasting maybe 3sec...)

If you could help me, that would be great ! :)

**Code:**

```
[fichier,directory]=uigetfile('*.wav'); //cibler fichier
cd('C:\Users\elise\Documents\COURS\Scilab\ProTools'); //aller dans le dossier
[music, meta] = loadwave(fichier); //charger la musique 

fqInit = meta(3); // initial frequency of the charged music

function [musicMod]=fadeIn(music,fqInit)
   tpsFadeIn = input('Entrez le temps du fondu (en s) : '); //duration of fadeIn
   nbEch = round(tpsFadeIn*fqInit); //number of sample concerned by fadeIn
   cm = [0:nbEch-1]/nbEch; //multiplier
   for k = 1 : size(music,1)-1
       cm=[cm; cm];
   end
   cm = [cm, ones(size(music,1), size(music,2)-nbEch)];
   musicMod = cm .* music; //modified music
   playsnd(musicMod,fqInit);
endfunction
```

Comment: Your function works fine for me. The fade obeys the length I wanted. Maybe you're using it wrong. Can you add to your example how do you use your function?

Comment: I found the solution, thanks for your answer!